# Replace <title></title> via htacces?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a website that loads in another website via .htaccess.

I don't have any access to the website that is loaded in, and I need to change the `<title></title>` of the website.

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?websitename\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.myurl.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website-name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.myurl.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

Comment: Already thought so. Any other way how I can achieve this? php or something?

Comment: Why can't you show the real title of the page you are sending ?

Comment: I don't have access to the page we're loading in.

Comment: I mean, you *can* change the title with javascript but most search engines will not notice it. Surely you could enable output buffering in PHP, print out your entire site, and then replace `<title>*</title>` in your buffer with whatever title you want. You can also just use PHP to put in the title right away when you generate it, but seeing as we have no idea how your site is made we can't say for sure.

Comment: Modifying the data is outside the scope of mod_rewrite. You'd need to apply an OutputFilter as well, and you'd probably have to custom write one (e.g. as a C extension to Apache or with mod_perl).

Answer (score 2):

There's an experimental module called [mod_sed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_sed.html) that could possibly be used for this purpose:

> `OutputSed` Directive
>
> - Description:    Sed command for filtering response content
> - Syntax: OutputSed sed-command
> - Context:    directory, .htaccess
> - Status: Experimental

Comment: you also have an example for the page title?

Comment: @LarsVelthuis Sorry, I'm a Windows user and I hardly have experience with sed. If you follow my link you'll reach sed's manual.